# When changing page or reload of page scroll to anchor tag in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-router, anchor

I am trying to scroll to anchor tags that are on the page which the content is populated via an API using axios. My issue is that the page doesn't scroll to the right point on reload / page change . I'm not sure what I'm missing/doing wrong.

On my react router I scroll the window to the top of the page as I want the user to start at the top of the page:

```
    ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route
      path="/"
      onChange={(prevState, nextState) => {
        if (nextState.location.action !== 'POP') {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
      }}
      component={App}
      >
      <IndexRoute pageId={5} background="" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/your-journey" pageId={7} component={YourJourney}/>
      <Route path="/designed-for-you" pageId={6} component={DesignedForYou}/>
      <Route path="/your-gateway" background="" pageId={1} component={YourGateway}/>
      <Route path="/get-in-touch" background="no-hero-image" pageId={4} component={GetInTouch}/>
      <Route path="/legal-and-compliance" background="no-hero-image" pageId={8} component={Legal}/>
      <Route path="/privacy" background="no-hero-image" pageId={9} component={Privacy}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I found out if I put the scroll to element function inside the render function of my page component when changing pages it worked but on reload it doesn't work.

This is the code inside my render function:

```
if (window.location.hash && this.state.dataLoaded) {
  console.log(this.state.dataLoaded);
  let offset = 0;
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    offset = 174;
  } else {
    offset = 150;
  }

  setTimeout(() => {
    scrollToElement(window.location.hash, {
      offset: -offset,
      ease: 'outSine',
      duration: 1500
    });
  }, 0);
}
```

The state that has dataLoaded gets setup like this:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  pageId: '',
  dataLoaded: false,
  data: {
    title: '',
    body: '',
    image: '',
    imageRows: [],
    footer: []
  }
};

 }
```

and then it gets set here in the componentDidMount function:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.serverRequest = axios.get(config.API_BASE + config.GALLERY_API + '/' + this.state.pageId).then(response => {
      if (this.unmounted) {
        return;
      }
      const res = response.data;

      if (response.status === 200) {
        this.setState({
          data: res,
          dataLoaded: true
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Has someone come across a good solution to do this? I can't use the scrollintoview function as there is no easing.

More info is I am using  tags to change pages.

Thanks

**EDIT**:
I have moved the scroll function to the componentDidMount function inside the promise/200 response if. I also have changed the set timeout to 250ms and this has solved my reload issue and going to the right place. I think/know this is a hack so please tell me otherwise on how to resolve this in a better way.